# Socket.io - Cannot connect to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I want to implement a simple [socket.io](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) connection to a client. For this purpose I use nodeJS with express.

My clients files look like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js" />
    <!--<script src="http://fb.me/react-0.12.2.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src='/javascripts/socket.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %> Juhu!</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

**socket.js**

```
/**
 * socket io connection
 */
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
```

My server site looks like that:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
//var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
//app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

**www.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('Test');
var app = require('../app');
var Pusher = require('pusher-client');
var http = require('http');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

//Create the HTTP server with the express app as an argument
var server = http.createServer(app);

/*var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});*/

/**
 * return pusher data
 */
var API_KEY = 'cb65d0a7a72cd94adf1f';
var pusher = new Pusher(API_KEY, {
    encrypted: true
});
var channel = pusher.subscribe("ticker.160");
channel.bind("message", function (data) {
    //console.log(data);
});


/**
 * Socket.io
 */
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server, {log: true});
var stream = channel.bind("message", function (data) {
    //console.log(data);
});

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
    // The user it's added to the array if it doesn't exist
    if(users.indexOf(socket.id) === -1) {
        users.push(socket.id);
    }

    // Log
    logConnectedUsers();

    /*// This is a listener to the signal "something"
     stream.on("start stream", function (data) {
     console.log("Test: ", data);
     socket.emit('info', { data: data });
     });*/

    // This handles when a user is disconnected
    socket.on("disconnect", function(o) {
        // find the user in the array
        var index = users.indexOf(socket.id);
        if(index != -1) {
            // Eliminates the user from the array
            users.splice(index, 1);
        }
        logConnectedUsers();
    });

});

// A log function for debugging purposes
function logConnectedUsers() {
    console.log("============= CONNECTED USERS ==============");
    console.log("== :: " + users.length);
    console.log("============================================");
}

//server listens
server.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

I expect when opening my browser I get at least a message that a new client connected in the nodejs app. However, I get nothing.

Any recommendation what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I changed the following code, however I still have no connection:

```
/**
 * Socket.io
 */
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server, {log: true});
var stream = channel.bind("message", function (data) {
    //console.log(data);
});

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    // The user it's added to the array if it doesn't exist
    if(users.indexOf(socket.id) === -1) {
        users.push(socket.id);
    }

    // Log
    logConnectedUsers();

    socket.emit('someevent', { attr: 'value' } )

    /*// This is a listener to the signal "something"
     stream.on("start stream", function (data) {
     console.log("Test: ", data);
     socket.emit('info', { data: data });
     });*/

    // This handles when a user is disconnected
    socket.on("disconnect", function(o) {
        // find the user in the array
        var index = users.indexOf(socket.id);
        if(index != -1) {
            // Eliminates the user from the array
            users.splice(index, 1);
        }
        logConnectedUsers();
    });

});
```

That`s all of my console output, when calling`localhost:3000`

```
Wed, 31 Dec 2014 11:24:00 GMT Test Express server listening on port 3000
GET / 304 19.798 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 15.385 ms - -
```

**UPDATE**

My index.js route file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Update**

I am now loadign my socket.js script from the client on the end of my page and get the following error message:

```
 GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/1/?t=1420027015782 400 
(Bad Request)socket.io.min.js:2 d.handshakesocket.io.min.js:2 d.connectsocket.io.min.js:2 dsocket.io.min.js:2 c.connectsocket.js:4 (anonymous function)
```

Comment: Try adding the "connection" event listener on your server: `io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});`

Comment: @pherris Thx for your answer! I do not get it. `io` listens already on the server. Where should I add it? Please give me a larger code snipped!

Comment: but you have `io.sockets.on("connection",` change that to @pherris code - without 'sockets'...

Comment: UPDATE: you should get the html page back in the browser displayed, after calling localhost:3000. 1. Do you? if not, specify routes for express at the server 2. after that, socketio.js should be downloaded from url you specified in html. Then js at the client should be executing and calling io.connect(). 3. then you should get at the piece of code at the server. Check the previous steps. (alerts, console.log into browser console windows can also help, and find out, what's wrong. The client code should be run after page is loaded at all. (e.g. with jquery - $(document).ready(function () {... )

Comment: UPDATE addition: You can programmatically test the loading of socketio.js with something similar to that code with jquery: `$(document).ready(function () {
    var mylink = serverConnectionUrl + '/socket.io/socket.io.js';
    $.getScript(mylink) 
 .fail(function (script, textStatus) {
  console.log('socket.io NOT loaded from ' + mylink);
  console.log('Is the server ' + serverConnectionUrl + ' running?');
 })
  
 .done(function (script, textStatus) {
  
 console.log('socket.io loaded from ' + mylink);
 var socket = new io.connect(serverConnectionUrl);`
... or do it manually.

Comment: (then of course don't use script tag in html) sorry for these updates..

Comment: Thx for your reply! What do you mean by 1? I posted by routs file in another update.

Comment: 1 - do you get your index.html in browser? if not, the problem is in the mapping. if yes, you can follow with 2.

Comment: @MiroslavMocek Ok I now switched my client script on the end of my page and I am getting an error message. I would appreciate your reply!

Comment: Thx for your support @MiroslavMocek. I resolved the issue by switching to `<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.6.js"></script>`, rathern than using the `0.9` version.

Comment: great! (sorry, i was away)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have until now, (strictly speaking) is client connecting to server. (html+socket.js calling `io.connect()` ).

Maybe you're asking about sending the data from server to the client?
Inside pherris's function, you can send the data to the client with

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected')
    socket.emit('someevent', { attr: 'value' } )
})
```

and catch it on the client side again with

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

socket.on('someevent', function (data) { console.log(data) })
```

And there send another event to the server.
The communication can be done in both ways. Depends on your needs.

Comment: Thx for your answer! However, I still face the problem of not having a connection. Please have a look at my update.